# pass inputs to the chatbot based on the user actions

Tags: asp.net, .net, bots, botframework, chatbot

I am working on a integillent bot for my application. Currently I have been able to create a chatbot, where the program answers the questions based on what the user types. i have referred this link : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/871501/Automated-Chat-Agent-in-ASP-NET-using-SIML-as-the . Now, I want the Bot to respond intelligently based on what the user clicks/selects  in my website, so mainly I want to pass the input to the chatbot pro-grammatically instead of the user typing his queries. Is this possible to do the same in .net/C#/VS-2015

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft Bot Framework?  Your question has the botframework tag, but it doesn't seem to apply: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/botframework/info  Using LUIS and the Bot Framework, you can easily add intelligence and plain language processing to a bot.  There are tons of examples online: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples